# how would i migrate from localStorage to ionic specific storage

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

i want to `migrate` from `localStorage` to `ionic 3` specific storage

**here is what i'm doing with `localStorage`**

```
  var allData = {"..":"..."};

   // setting item

    localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(allData));

  // getting item

    this.userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData")); // will be available throughout my app
```

**for ionic 3 storage i tried like this**

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

  var allData = {"..":"..."};

  // setting item

   storage.set('userData', allData);

  // getting item

  this.userData =  storage.get('age').then((val) => {
                      return val;
                  });
```

i want to `retain` data from `storage` into `this.userData`

**but it is not working as desired why ?**

please help me thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try below. Storage returns promise you have to use like below

```
storage.get('age').then((val) => 
{
   this.userData =  val
});
```

Comment: oho, with the above code i, can retrieve data throughout my page? is it?

Comment: Yes you can use this.userData but dont forgot javascript is working in synchronous method so if you try to use this.userData after that statement still they return undefined because when you try to get data from storage they take some time so next statement cannot wait for complete above

Comment: So when your application start you have to get data from storage and store to some global variable so you access that easily without promise then load your page